# Задать фокус текстбокса

Tags: c#, wpf

Я в событии LostFocus проверяю валидность введенных данных (кстати никто не знает как это сделать лучше? Чтобы вообще ввести неверные данные нельзя было, типа MaskedTextBox из Windows Forms.) И если введены неверные данные, то я вывожу ошибку и хочу установить обратно фокус. Но вместо этого у меня происходит какая то бесконечная рекурсия и выкидывает ошибку переполнения стека.

```
private void tbBottom_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var value = 0.0;

    if (!double.TryParse(tbBottom.Text, out value) || value < 0 || value > 10000 || BottomValue >= TopValue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrectly set. The value must adhere to the following rules: Bottom >= 0 && Bottom < 10000 && Bottom < Top.", "Setting error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        tbBottom.Focus();
        return;
    }

    BottomValue = value;
}
```

Comment: Вставляешь код , выделяешь его и жмешь ctrl+K ( это к вопросу как вставлять тут код )

Answer (score 1):

[Отсюда](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave,
>   LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers.Doing so can cause
>   your application or the operating system to stop responding.

Нельзя устанавливать фокус из обработчика LostFocus.

И [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/19562/) немного про валидацию в WPF.

Comment: так это же Windows Forms вроде. В WCF у TextBox нет такого события.

Comment: Коcяк, второй тэг не заметил. Но правило что нельзя устанавливать фокус в обработчике смены фокуса у MS вроде как распространяется вообще на всё, начиная ещё с WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать уже готовый контрол с маской из **Extended WPF Toolkit**?

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox x:Name="_maskedTextBox" Mask="(000) 000-0000" ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}" />
```

[Подробнее тут](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home)

[Скачать тут](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: не уверен что этот контрол сможет задать все именно так как мне надо. Ну вот скажем какую мне маску задать чтобы были только цифры + чтобы число было >= 0 и <= 10000. Так ведь мало того у меня еще сравнение там с другой переменной, а тут я думаю маска уже ничем не поможет.

Comment: @DarkByte для ввода только цифр - подойдет маска. Во все остальном - предлагаю отказаться от фокуса контрола и использовать `TextBox.TextChanged event` и проверять текст контрола на валидность каждый раз при изменении.

Comment: с чего бы вдруг TextChanged? LostFocus куда удобнее, зачем это надо чтобы при вводе каждого символа срабатывало событие? Лучше просто один раз при потере фокуса. Я же говорю у меня просто проблема с установкой фокуса обратно в случае ошибки.

Comment: @DarkByte вполне адекватный другой ответ) с фокусами никогда не работал и скорее всего не буду из за некорректного срабатывания время от времени. Бороться с этим - себе дороже

Comment: TextChanged тоже ужасно неудобная и корявая штука, я щас попробовал вот тот же самый код вставить в обработчик TextChanged (LostFocus убрал) - то и дело срабатывает тогда когда все правильно, а когда не правильно не срабатывает. Да еще этот messagebox на каждой неверно введенной цифре бесит. Лучше бы что то более интерактивное...